# Find complex roots for every e^(i phi) with 0 <= phi < 4pi

Tags: python, numpy

I want to find the complex roots for z1 = -0.9 and z2 = 0.3 but for every phi between 0 and 4pi.

```
phi = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 400, endpoint=False)

e = np.exp(1j*phi)
z1 = [-0.9, -0.25, -0.99, -0.9405, -0.76, -1.019898, -1.00]
z2 = [0.3, 0.25, 0.11, 0.0495, 0.04, 0.000102, 1.00]

#Coefficients 

P = [e, -e*(2*z1[0] + 2*z2[0]), e*(z1[0]**2 + z2[0]**2 + 4*z1[0]*z2[0] - 1), -e*((2*z1[0]**2 * z2[0]) + (2*z1[0]*z2[0]**2)), (z1[0]*z2[0])*(z1[0]*z2[0] + 1)]

#Output

ROOT = np.roots(P)

print(ROOT)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py:65: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. 
If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
   ary = asanyarray(ary)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/4090299359.py in <module>
     18 #Outputting the roots
     19 
---> 20 ROOT = np.roots(P)
     21 
     22 print(ROOT)

<__array_function__ internals> in roots(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in roots(p)
    232 
    233     # find non-zero array entries
--> 234     non_zero = NX.nonzero(NX.ravel(p))[0]
    235 
    236     # Return an empty array if polynomial is all zeros

<__array_function__ internals> in nonzero(*args, **kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in nonzero(a)
   1919 
   1920     """
-> 1921     return _wrapfunc(a, 'nonzero')
   1922 
   1923 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55 
     56     try:
---> 57         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58     except TypeError:
     59         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I also went and tried a.all() on 'phi', I'm not sure how to fix it so I just place it randomly hoping the error would go away:

```
phi = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 400, endpoint=False).all()
```

And I only get 4 roots, instead of 4 roots for every phi. How can I fix this? Any actual help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Show the FULL error message!  Where the error kccurs is important.  Putting an `all` in the wrong place doesn't do you any good.

Comment: I just added the full error, thanks for telling me to that. But 'Putting an all in the wrong place doesn't do you any good.' Well, that's the whole point of me posting this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

phi = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 400, endpoint=False)

e = np.exp(1j*phi)
z1 = [-0.9, -0.25, -0.99, -0.9405, -0.76, -1.019898, -1.00]
z2 = [0.3, 0.25, 0.11, 0.0495, 0.04, 0.000102, 1.00]

#Coefficients 

P = [e,
     -e*(2*z1[0] + 2*z2[0]),
     e*(z1[0]**2 + z2[0]**2 + 4*z1[0]*z2[0] - 1),
     -e*((2*z1[0]**2 * z2[0]) + (2*z1[0]*z2[0]**2)),
     (z1[0]*z2[0])*(z1[0]*z2[0] + 1)
     ]
# the last element of "P" is just a float, but the others are arrays...
# Is this really so different?
    
#Output

n_phi = len(phi)
ROOT = np.zeros((n_phi, 4), dtype=complex)

# apply "np.roots" for each point, one by one
for i in range(n_phi):
    # change new_P if the last element of "P" should be a array
    new_P = [P[0][i], P[1][i], P[2][i], P[3][i], P[4]]
    ROOT[i, :] = np.roots(new_P)

print(ROOT)
# For a more readable presentation you can use this:
# with np.printoptions(precision=2, linewidth=85):
#     print(ROOT)
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see where I went wrong now. I want to upvote but I can't, but thank you!